# Close vote from a gold badge holder is not closing the question immediately

Tags: support, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Few minutes back, I casted a close vote (duplicate) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311733/how-to-print-address-of-a-variable-in-c).

I have a gold badge in `C` and as per my understanding, the question should get to "closed" staus immediately. However, it's not.

What did I miss? (*cacheing, maybe?*)

- Screenshot of my vote

[image: Vote casted]

Comment: thanks @crabolo, I'll accept this dupe. :)

Comment: The more hapless the questioner, and thus the more likely he'll pick the wrong tags or ask a duplicate question, the less likely a gold badge owner can close the question.  It is an idiotic rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original tags are the important ones when it comes to the golden dupe hammer. Your gold badge must match the original tags. In this case the question was originally tagged with just the [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32311733/revisions

Comment: Ahh...silly me. Noted. Thanks for the info. :)